# How to get URL of category of a custom post?

Tags: theme-development

I`ve created a custom post type with categories. How can I get the URL to display only posts from a specyfic category of that custom post type?

Comment: Please add some more information. What do you mean by "the URL"? What have you tried?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking for a Taxonomy query... or a way to get terms, does one of these solutions answer your question. Please don't downvote as I am going of very limited information and guessing here at what you need.

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post-type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'tax_query' => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'taxname_tax',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => 'term-to-query'
        )
      )
    );
  $listing_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ( $listing_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $listing_query->have_posts() ) : $listing_query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php the_title(); ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; // end of taxonomy query loop. ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>



// or a taxonomy lookup
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonamy_tax' ); ?>
<?php foreach( $terms as $term ) echo $term->slug; ?>
```